# NSUserDefaults to AppleWatch

Tags: iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I currently driving crazy cause i can't find my mistake.
I try to pass some information over to my WatchKit App, but this does not work for me.

Both are in the same group

[image]

Then i start with the Watch with

```
NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.WatchDate")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("1", forKey: "TEST")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

after launch the app once on the watch i switch over to the "phone app" and let it println() the stored value

```
NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.WatchDate")
println("Saved Informations:")
println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("TEST"))
```

The output always is "nil"

[image]

I tried the same passing information the other way, also with no success.
But if i simply println() the stored value on the same "device" it works.

Any idea what i m doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zisoft has the right point, but to my belief, my code is the safer and cleaner (more readable) way to do it. I´m also taking into consideration, that naming your App Group without using reverse-DNS-style is not considered best practice.

Set data:

```
import Foundation

if let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mycompany.WatchDate") {
    sharedDefaults.setObject("1", forKey: "TEST")
    sharedDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

Read data:

```
import Foundation

if let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mycompany.WatchDate") {
    if let sharedString = sharedDefaults.objectForKey("TEST") as? String {
        println(sharedString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSUserDefaults(suiteName)` already returns a `NSUserDefaults` object, so you must not call `standardUserDefaults()` again on it. Try it this way:

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.WatchDate")
sharedDefaults?.setObject("1", forKey: "TEST")
sharedDefaults?.synchronize()
```

on the other side:

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.WatchDate")
let s = sharedDefaults?.objectForKey("TEST") as! String
println(s)
```

Comment: Your code crashes, if there is no suite named 'group.WatchDate'. try using 'if let'!

Comment: @stk: No, the code does not crash, due to `?`. It only executes when the object is not nil

Comment: Did you actually run the code? I´m getting a compile error: `Expected type after 'as'`. There is no `as!` to force unwrapping, just leave out the `?`. If I´m force unwrapping it, there is a runtime error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: Ah - you are on Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.2). Then you are right and you have to change the syntax and use `if let ...`